# Running a javascript after ajax load

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI. I'm loading some content in a dialog box over AJAX. After inserting the content from the server, I need to make modifications to the document. I am using the *.live()* function on my link; I thought this would enable me to use Js after loading the content over ajax, but it's like the content I just loaded isn't a part of the document. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your code / AJAX call. You probably can add a callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding the bindings (lives) in the success function of the ajax call?

If so I had the same issue, I'll try to explain what I figured out:

```
$.post('callURL', function(data){

    // Let's say data returned from server is an ID of a div I have to hide
    // by clicking on some_link

    $('#some_link').live('click',function(){

        $('#'+data).hide();

    });

});
```

This won't work because the code inside the 'live' function is executed on click and at that time the 'data' value is gone.

To make it work I made a global variable 'ID' which I set in the success function and then called in the 'live' function again like this:

```
var ID;    

$.post('callURL', function(data){

    // Let's say data returned from server is an ID of a div I have to hide
    // by clicking on some_link

    ID = data

    $('#some_link').live('click',function(){

        $('#'+ID).hide();

    });

});
```